# How to display data in TextView

Tags: android

I have a view in which there is a text box where user enters data, when clicks on submit, I want to store the input and display in another box.

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
```

How can I do it, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
mText.setText(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String info = edittext.getText().toString();
mText.setText(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
TextView mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
String storedData = edittext.getText().toString();
mText.setText(storedData);
```

Here, you can use the string storedData in another activity or to setText for another editText (textbox)